# How to implement String contains with equals ignore case to filter content of a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a json file in the below format:

```
{Continent: Asia, Description: Biggest continent in the WORLD},
{Continent: Europe, Description: Coldest countries in the world}
{Continent: Africa, Description: Second continent in the WorLD}
{Continent: Australia, Description: The only country & continent in the world}
```

I am trying to filter the rows of the dataframe that contains the string `world` in it.
I wrote the following code for it.

```
val continents = spark.read.json("path/to/input.json")
```

To filter the rows containing the word `world` in the column `Description`

```
continents.filter($"Description".contains("world"))
```

The above line only filters the rows only if `world` is completely in lower case.

Is there any way I can apply a filter where case is ignored ?

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, you can convert the whole description to `upper` or `lower` case, in the following case I have converted the description to lower case for comparison.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower


continents.filter(lower($"Description").contains("world"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with column to change the description to lowercase and add more complex functions. Filter out on new column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col

continents.withColumn('lower_desc', lower(col('Description'))
continents.filter($"lower_desc".contains("world"))
```

Comment: There's no need to add a new column